# Error building angular app image using docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I was trying to dockerize my angular application and faced this error. When I run npm run build locally I was able to get the build success though. If someone can tell me what could be possibly going wrong it might be helpful.

Error in console while building the image. (docker build -t image-name:tag ).

```
 => ERROR [build 6/6] RUN npm run build                                                                                                                   74.9s 
------
 > [build 6/6] RUN npm run build:
#13 5.357
#13 5.357 > dev-ng-build@0.0.0 build /home/app
#13 5.357 > ng build
#13 5.357
#13 9.517 Warning: Support was requested for IE 11 in the project's browserslist configuration. IE 11 support is deprecated since Angular v12.
#13 9.517 For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
#13 9.541 - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
#13 74.69 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
#13 74.70 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 /home/app/src/app/about/about.component.css - Error: /home/app/src/app/about/about.component.css from Css Minimizer
#13 74.71 Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 /home/app/src/app/algorithms/algorithms.component.css - Error: /home/app/src/app/algorithms/algorithms.component.css from Css Minimizer
#13 74.71 Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 /home/app/src/app/app.component.css - Error: /home/app/src/app/app.component.css from Css Minimizer
#13 74.71 Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 /home/app/src/app/binary-search/binary-search.component.css - Error: /home/app/src/app/binary-search/binary-search.component.css from Css Minimizer   
#13 74.71 Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 /home/app/src/app/creator/creator.component.css - Error: /home/app/src/app/creator/creator.component.css from Css Minimizer
#13 74.71 Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 /home/app/src/app/home/home.component.css - Error: /home/app/src/app/home/home.component.css from Css Minimizer
#13 74.71 Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 /home/app/src/app/sort/sort.component.css - Error: /home/app/src/app/sort/sort.component.css from Css Minimizer
#13 74.71 Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
#13 74.71     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:437:19)
#13 74.71     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:425:5)
#13 74.71     at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:316:11)
#13 74.71     at Object.writeToStdin (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1725:19)
#13 74.71     at sendRequest (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:617:14)
#13 74.71     at start (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1294:9)
#13 74.71     at Object.transform2 [as transform] (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1304:5)
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1781:55
#13 74.71     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
#13 74.71     at Object.transform (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1781:14)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 Error: Optimization error [polyfills-es5.d4ea99cfa27f021dc910.js]: Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 Error: Optimization error [main-es2017.c2d65b1e7d53ffd3a0e5.js]: Error: The service is no longer running
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at sendRequest (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:605:14)
#13 74.71     at start (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1254:9)
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1624:81
#13 74.71     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:154:23)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 Error: Optimization error [runtime-es2017.27f7497455417d37f3da.js]: Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71 Error: Optimization error [polyfills-es2017.12d7b13599cb68ca3ce3.js]: Error: The service was stopped
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1256:29
#13 74.71     at /home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
#13 74.71     at Socket.afterClose (/home/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:587:7)
#13 74.71     at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
#13 74.71     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
#13 74.71     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
#13 74.71
#13 74.71
#13 74.81 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#13 74.81 npm ERR! errno 1
#13 74.81 npm ERR! dev-ng-build@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
#13 74.81 npm ERR! Exit status 1
#13 74.81 npm ERR!
#13 74.81 npm ERR! Failed at the dev-ng-build@0.0.0 build script.
#13 74.82 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#13 74.83
#13 74.83 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#13 74.83 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-05T15_36_53_446Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

Please find the Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:14.18.0-slim As build

WORKDIR /home/app

#Copy package.json
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

#Install dependencies
RUN npm install

#Copy other files and folder to working directory
COPY . .

#Build Angular application in PROD mode
RUN npm run build

#Download NGINX Image
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

#Copy built angular files to NGINX HTML folder
COPY --from=build /home/app/dist/dev-ng-build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406169/angular-build-in-docker-fails-err-stream-destroyed-cannot-call-write-after-a

Comment: To double-check, do you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the host's `node_modules` directory?

Comment: After adding node_modules and npm-debug.log to .dockerignore image got created successfully. Thanks !!!. @DavidMaze